# datatables urlrewrite when use ajax

Tags: ajax, url-rewriting, datatables

help.i can't find my problem.

when i set datatables as follow, all things run as i want.
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": contextPath + "/commodity/ajax/brands",

but when i change the sAjaxSource as follow,the ajax error function happened.
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": contextPath + "/commodity/ajax/products"

i used chorme and got url changed to  http://***:8080/tire/tire/app/main

the controller in java like : 
 @RequestMapping(value = "/commodity/ajax/products")

@RequestMapping(value = "/commodity/ajax/brands")

is the problem for urlrewrite?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you change the url to ****/app/main from another, seems you use Spring MVC, so you should check your web.xml and to see which url-pattern that the servlet: DispatchServlet specified to. Because just the url that matchs this pattern can be handle by your controller that annotated with @Controller.